# Regex getting multiple numbers

Tags: regex

the following works:

```
/<(?:CURRENCY):[ ]*([\w\s]+(\s*,\s*)\d+(\s*\d+)*)>/i
```

for:

```
<currency: Sample Name, 76>
```

But now I want to change this to: `<currency: Sample Name, 76, 76>`

I don't know regex enough to be able to change this I have tried: `/<(?:CURRENCY):[ ]*([\w\s]+(\s*,\s*,\s*)\d+(\s*\d+\s*\d+)*)>/i`

But it doesn't work. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These regexes are strange.

- `(?:CURRENCY)`: why use a non-capturing group here, if you are not doing anything with the group?
- `[ ]*`: a character class with a single character? Why not simply a space star?

etc

Here's how I would do it (assuming it can have many numbers at the end, like `<currency: Sample Name, 23, 24, 25>`):

```
<currency: *[\w ]+(,\s*\d+)+>
```

If you need to match exactly only two numbers at the end:

```
<currency: *[\w ]+(,\s*\d+){2}>
```

You can change `{2}` to any number of repetitions, and use `{2,}` for a minimum number but no upper bound.

You may want to add capturing groups `(` `)` as needed. You can also use some online tool like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to test your regexes.

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
/<(?:CURRENCY):[ ]*([\w\s]+,\s*\d+(,\s*\d+\s*)*)>/i
```

I think this part `(\s*,\s*,\s*)` is looking for too many commas and this part 
`(\s*\d+\s*\d+)` is not accounting for commas.